# Can't change the base folder for lite-server in Angular 2 application

Tags: node.js, angular, browser-sync, lite-server

I am going through the [5 minute quickstart of Angular 2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html). However, my application resides in `src/` folder instead of at the root of my repository, and when I run `npm start` the application is trying to find an `index.html` file at the root. I read up on `lite-server` and documentation shows that it uses `BrowserSync` and I can reconfigure `BrowserSync` with a `bs-config.json` in my repository. I did that and this is what my config looks like:

```
{
  "port": 8123,
  "server": { "baseDir": "./src" }
}
```

According to the log it's using the specified config:

```
[1] > todo-app-angular2@1.0.0 lite E:\GitHub\todo-app-angular2
[1] > lite-server "./bs-config.json"
```

I also tried an override through bs-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  port: 8123,
  server: {
    baseDir: "./src"
  }
};
```

However the Angular application is still opened on port 3000 and it's disregarding the baseDir defined in the config. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try adding `--config path/to/bs-config.json` in `npm start` command

Comment: Be sure to use lite-server v2 for the browser sync config options file

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use a file called `bs-config.js` (instead of a `bs-config.json` one) since lite-server tries to load a module using the `require` function. The configuration should be a valid Node module:

```
module.exports = {
  "port": 8123,
  "server": { "baseDir": "./src" }
};
```

See this line in the source code: https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server/blob/master/lib/lite-server.js#L20.

This file by default is loaded from the user's project folder.

**Edit**

After digging a bit more, the first part of my answer relies on the code from github but not the one actually installed using `npm install` (version 1.3.4)

There are two options in this case:

- **port**
- **baseDir**

Using this command will fix your problem:

```
$ lite-server --baseDir ./src --port 3333
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: I actually forgot to mention that I already tried this. I replaced the json config with a module.export in a bs-config.js file. That still did nothing :( Actually when I added this my npm start would fail.

Comment: I just tried it and it still serves from ./
[1] [BS] Access URLs:
[1]  ------------------------------------
[1]        Local: http://localhost:3000
[1]     External: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3000
[1]  ------------------------------------
[1]           UI: http://localhost:3001
[1]  UI External: http://xx.xx.xx.xx:3001
[1]  ------------------------------------
[1] [BS] Serving files from: ./

Comment: Which version of lite-server do you use?

Comment: "lite-server": "^1.3.4"

Comment: Same for me! If you have a look at the file `node_modules/lite-server/lib/lite-server.js` you will see that `argv.baseDir` (`--baseDir`) is used for base folder and `argv.port` for port (`--port`). You could add some `console.log`s in the file to see received values... I made a new test and the following command works for me `lite-server --baseDir ./src --port 3333`...

Comment: Ok, I apologize. That actually worked. I added the params to my npm start, but I should have added it to my npm lite which is called by npm start.

Comment: @ThierryTemplier Is it possible to configure the files that are being watched from by browser-sync with the `lite-server` script?

Comment: @ShawnNorthrop yes you can leverage the `--files` parameter. Specify the file patterns at this level. Something like `./**/*.js`...

Comment: Be sure to use lite-server v2 for the browser sync config options file

Comment: @ThierryTemplier I'm facing same issue, can you kindly let me know where should i use `$ lite-server --baseDir ./src --port 3333
`.  I have npm 3.7.3 version in windows.

Answer (score 5):

The answer from `Thierry Templier` is not quite correct (anymore), you can use either the `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` configuration to adjust your browser-sync configuration. This is what I came up initially for the [angular2 quick start example](https://github.com/ibqn/ng2-quick-start/blob/a957aa5e36df2d2414fb8aba4a02b0f6c0445e6d/bs-config.json) with JIT(Just-In-Time) and AOT(Ahead-Of-Time) compilation support (`bs-config.json`)

```
{
  "port": 8000,
  "server": ["app", "."]
}
```

to host the project from multiple directories.

However, I did not like this solution because by overwriting the `server` section in the `json` file, the default `middleware` configuration was overwritten at the same time.

Therefore I ended with the following approach, I took the default [lite-server](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server/blob/master/lib/config-defaults.js)'s `config-defaults.js` files and modified it instead ([bs-config.js](https://github.com/ibqn/ng2-quick-start/blob/06ccf377c13a68e1b61b50ab54b1ae1cdd171294/bs-config.js)):

```
'use strict';
var fallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
var log = require('connect-logger');
/*
 | For up-to-date information about the options:
 |   http://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/
 */
module.exports = {
  port: 8000,
  injectChanges: false, // workaround for Angular 2 styleUrls loading
  filters: ['./**/*.{html,htm,css,js}'],
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: 'node_modules'
  },
  server: ['./', 'app'],
  middleware: [
    log({ format: '%date %status %method %url' }),
    fallback({
        index: '/index.html',
        htmlAcceptHeaders: ['text/html', 'application/xhtml+xml'] // systemjs workaround
    })
  ]
};
```