# Angular - What is the meanings of module.id in component?

Tags: angular, systemjs, angular2-components

In an Angular app, I have seen that `@Component` has property `moduleId`. What does it mean?

And when `module.id` is not defined anywhere, the app still works. How can it still work?

```javascript
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'ng-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css'],
  directives: [AppComponent]
});
```

Comment: I get 404 for the link

Comment: Updated link: https://blog.schwarty.com/angular2-beta-relative-paths-for-templateurl-and-styleurls-dff1ed15a0d3

Answer (score 184, accepted):

The beta release of Angular (since vesion 2-alpha.51) supports relative assets for components, like **templateUrl** and **styleUrls** in the `@Component` decorator.

`module.id` works when using CommonJS. You don't need to worry about how it works.

> **Remember**: setting moduleId: module.id in the @Component decorator is
>   the key here. If you don't have that then Angular 2 will be looking
>   for your files at the root level.

Source from [Justin Schwartzenberger's post](http://schwarty.com/2015/12/22/angular2-relative-paths-for-templateurl-and-styleurls/), thanks to [@Pradeep Jain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5043867/pardeep-jain)

**Update on 16 Sep 2016:**

> If you are using **webpack** for bundling then you don't need
>   `module.id` in decorator. Webpack plugins auto handle (add it)
>   `module.id` in final bundle

Comment: How does this explain what module.id is?

Comment: @gyozokudor 
 If you don't have that then Angular 2 will be looking for your files at the root level.

Answer (score 91):

**Update for (2017-03-13)**:

> All mention of moduleId removed. "Component relative paths" cookbook deleted
>
> We added a new SystemJS plugin (systemjs-angular-loader.js) to our recommended SystemJS configuration. This plugin dynamically converts "component-relative" paths in templateUrl and styleUrls to "absolute paths" for you.
>
> We strongly encourage you to only write component-relative paths. That is the only form of URL discussed in these docs. You no longer need to write `@Component({ moduleId: module.id })`, nor should you.

Source: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/change-log.html

**Definition:**

```
moduleId?: string
```

`moduleId` parameter inside the `@Component` annotation takes a `string` value which is;

"*The module id of the module that contains the component.*"

CommonJS usage: `module.id`,

SystemJS usage: `__moduleName`

---

**Reason to use `moduleId`**:

`moduleId` is used to resolve relative paths for your stylesheets and templates as it says in the documentation.

> The module id of the module that contains the component. Needed to be able to resolve relative urls for templates and styles. In Dart, this can be determined automatically and does not need to be set. In CommonJS, this can always be set to module.id.

ref(old): https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ComponentMetadata-class.html

> we can specify locations of the template and style files relative to the component class file simply by setting the moduleId property of the @Component metadata

ref: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html

---

**Example usage:**

Folder structure:

```
RootFolder
├── index.html
├── config.js
├── app
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── my.component.ts
│   │   ├── my.component.css
│   │   ├── my.component.html
```

**Without module.id**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/my.component.html', <- Starts from base path
  styleUrls:  ['app/components/my.component.css'] <- Starts from base path
})
```

**With module.id**:

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs", <- need to change this if you want to use module.id property
...
```

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: 'my.component.html', <- relative to the components current path
  styleUrls:  ['my.component.css'] <- relative to the components current path
})
```

Comment: But how it works, where is the reference of module.id

Comment: @NishchitDhanani it isn't necessary but i suggest checking https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6053 it maps to your `map` keys inside your config. Like `app`.

Comment: echonax's link to the docs is currently not working -- even though it is the link on the Angular.io Component page. Try: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ComponentMetadata-class.html

Comment: It looks like that you forgot the 'components' sub-directory of the 'app' root-directory in the approach without module.id, isn't it?  I think it should be: 
`templateUrl: 'app/components/my.component.html', styleUrls:  ['app/components/my.component.css']`

Answer (score 23):

If you get `typescript error`, just `declare` the variable in your file.

```
// app.component.ts
declare var module: {
   id: string;
}
//
@Component({
   moduleId: module.id,    // now it works without annoying Typescript
   ...
})
```

## `UPDATE - December 08, 2016`

The `module` keyword is available on `node`.  So if you install `@types/node`, in your project, you will have `module` keyword automatically available in your typescript files without needing to `declare` it.

`npm install -D @types/node`

#### Depending on your configuration, you *might* have to include this in your `tsconfig.json` file to get the *tooling*:

```
//tsconfig.json
{
   ...
   "compilerOptions": {
       "types" : ["node"]
   }
   ...
}

// some-component.ts
// now, no need to declare module
@Component({
   moduleId: module.id,    // now it works without annoying Typescript
   ...
})
```

Good Luck

Comment: tnq so much! finally i got my `ng build --prod --aot` working by doing `npm install -D @types/node` after spending a long time of fiddling :)

Comment: one more thing I did was `moduleId: 'module.id'` (notice the single quotes around module.id)

Comment: @AnandRockzz I am glad you found this post helpful.  

I don't think you need to add `module.id` as a string.  If it worked, something seems to be incorrect.  You may need to research this further.

Answer (score 4):

**As per Angular doc, You should not use @Component({ moduleId: module.id })**

Please ref : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/change-log.html

Here is the relevant text from that page:

**All mention of moduleId removed. "Component relative paths" cookbook deleted (2017-03-13)**

We added a new SystemJS plugin (`systemjs-angular-loader.js`) to our recommended SystemJS configuration. This plugin dynamically converts "component-relative" paths in templateUrl and styleUrls to "absolute paths" for you.

We strongly encourage you to only write component-relative paths. That is the only form of URL discussed in these docs. You no longer need to write `@Component({ moduleId: module.id })`, nor should you.

Comment: I will also add this to my answer as a disclaimer, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the great explanations from `echonax` and `Nishchit Dhanani` I want to add, that I really hate population of components with `module.id`. Especially, if you have support for the (Ahead-of-Time) [AoT-compilation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#compile) and for a realistic project this is what you should aim for, there is no place for something like `module.id` in your component metadata.

From the [Docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#compile):

> JiT-compiled applications that use the `SystemJS` loader and component-relative URLs must set the `@Component.moduleId` property to `module.id`. The module object is undefined when an AoT-compiled app runs. The app fails with a null reference error unless you assign a global module value in the index.html like this:

```
<script>window.module = 'aot';</script>
```

**I think having this line in the production version of the `index.html` file is absolutely not acceptable!**

Therefore, the goal is to have have (Just-in-Time) JiT-compilation for development and AoT support for production with the following component metadata definition: (without `moduleId: module.id` line)

```
@Component({      
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: 'my.component.html', <- relative to the components current path
  styleUrls:  ['my.component.css'] <- relative to the components current path
})
```

At the same time I would like to place styles, like `my.component.css` and template files, like `my.component.html` **relative** to the component `my.component.ts` file paths.

To achieve all this, the solution I am using is to host web server (lite-server or browser-sync) during development phase from multiple directory sources!

`bs-config.json`:

```
{
  "port": 8000,
  "server": ["app", "."]
}
```

Please take a took at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41169019/5739875) for me details.

The exemplary angular 2 quick start project, which relies on this approach is hosted [here](https://github.com/ibqn/ng2-quick-start).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like if your using "module": "es6" in tsconfig.json, you dont have to use this :)

Comment: will it not *transpile* into ES6 if we do this?

Answer (score 0):

This moduleId value is used by the Angular reflection processes and the metadata_resolver component to evaluate the fully-qualified component path before the component is constructed.

Answer (score -2):

Adding `moduleId: module.id` fixes several issues that can occur when building native-angular apps and angular web apps. It's best practice to use it.

It also enables the component to look in the current directory for files instead of from the top folder