# TSLint complains @Component's module.id "Corresponding file not included in tsconfig.json" (in WebStorm)

Tags: angular, typescript2.0, tslint

Simple problem, in WebStorm:

[image: @Component moduleId: module.id tslint error: Corresponding file is not included in tsconfig.json]

In addition to that, `tsc` complains with:

```
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.
```

I'm looking either:

1. For something like [jshint's `"predef"`](http://jshint.com/docs/) key that allows you to ignore global variables that are defined above the scope of the active inspection, or
2. To add some annotation or import to my `@Component` that I have forgotten to allow TSLint to see `module`, [which comes from SystemJS](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6053).

Importantly, I *do not* want to add in-code `//noinspection TypeScriptUnresolvedVariable` because this `moduleId: module.id` pattern [is well-known for Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178192/angular2-what-is-the-meanings-of-module-id-in-component) and required in every single component we have. It doesn't look like something that should be ignored systemically.

I noticed that TSLint [has an `ignore-pattern` directive](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/pull/981/commits/c7e5002043475b746e20fc4535e1bb51feb78655), but it's a subset of `no-unused-variable`, which is not what I'm looking for.

I'm using WebStorm 2016.2.4 with TSLint 2 locally. Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.3",
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ],
  "filesGlob": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I have also tried

```
"compilerOptions" {
  "target": "es5",
  "module: "commonjs",
  ... }
```

To no avail.

Comment: Did you install @types/node?

Comment: @pe8ter Good question! Yes, but that's another problem. I have indeed `npm i "@types/node"` but tsc also _always_ complains with `node_modules/@types/node/index.d.ts(283,40): error TS1110: Type expected.`, though it seems unrelated.

Comment: A few things look off in your tsconfig.json: typeRoots belongs in compilerOptions and "filesGlob" should be renamed to "include". http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: Are you using WebStorm's bundled TypeScript compiler? 2016.2.4 comes with TypeScript compiler version 1.8.10. You need to point it at a newer version.

Comment: @pe8ter I am indeed using TS2 (I pointed the Custom TypeScript location to my `node_modules/typescript/lib/` folder).

Comment: Could you try `./node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc -v`. The error "Type expected" at line 283 is for a nullable type, which is only available in TS 2. That suggests you're still using TS 1.x.

Comment: It went away of its own accord, for whatever reason. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose it was caused by something transient, as I have not seen it for weeks.