# Relative path is not working in Angular2 component

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Logo not loading in Angular 2 in a component (Navbar)

#### navbar component file:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

  private website:string
  private websiteUrl:string
  constructor() {  
    this.website = 'Rakesh'
    this.websiteUrl = 'http://google.com'
   }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

i add some html code in template file and  the logo not loading

#### my logo code is

```xml
<div class="navbar-header">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{websiteUrl}}">
  *<img src="./logo/rakesh.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Image">*
  </a>
</div>
```

Output in console
`moduleId should be a string in "NavbarComponent"`.

#### my Logo path:

```
navabar.component.ts
logo/
    rakesh.png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem maybe comes from `moduleId should be a string in "NavbarComponent"`.

As Angular CLI now use Webpack, module.id in Webpack is a number, while Angular expects a string. What you should do is remove the `moduleId` metadata.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
```

Comment: Yes, I had this problem, and because I use Webpack, I have to remove this.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `module.id` from `@Component`. It doesn't need anymore, you can find it in `@NgModule` since Angular 2.0.

This is how webpack users use  [component relative paths](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html#!#webpack) instead of `module.id`.

> ### Webpack: load templates and styles
>
> Webpack developers have an alternative to `moduleId`.
>
> They can load templates and styles at runtime by adding `./` at the
>   beginning of the template and `styles / styleUrls` properties that
>   reference *component-relative* URLS.
>
> ```js
> import { Component } from '@angular/core';
>
> import '../../public/css/styles.css';
>
> @Component({
>   selector: 'my-app',
>   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
>   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
> })
> export class AppComponent { }
> ```
>
> Webpack will do a `require` behind the scenes to load the templates
>   and styles. Read more [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html#highlights).

---

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40434390/573032) answer can help you if you have compilation errors in typescript.

> If you get typescript error, just declare the variable in your file.
>
> ```js
> declare var module: {
>    id: string;
> }
>
> @Component({
>    moduleId: module.id,   
>    ...
> })
> ```

Comment: @RakeshRoy Make sure you accept correct answer to help other visitors.