# Bringing unit testing to angular2 app with karma and systemjs (templateUrl path issue)

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner, systemjs, angular2-aot

I have a small trivial angular2 [application](https://github.com/ibqn/ng2-quick-start) which is relying on `systemjs` with JiT and AoT compilation.

The key difference here, compared to other setups is that I explicitly do not want to set the `moduleId: module.id` into the definition of the component, as there is absolutely no use for it during the AoT compilation (which stands for the desired end-result for production). To get things going in the JiT mode I prefer to host testing server from multiple folders (cp. this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178192/angular2-what-is-the-meanings-of-module-id-in-component/41170237#41170237))

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  // moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  ...
}
```

The only bottleneck here is that I cannot get karma based unit tests working as I was not able to find a way to proxy the template file to the correct location...

When I run karma I am struggling to proxy the path to the template file:

```
[1] 08 02 2017 13:03:20.768:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.4.1 server started
... 
[1] 08 02 2017 13:03:22.579:WARN [web-server]: 404: /app.component.html
    Chrome 56.0.2924 (Linux 0.0.0) AppComponent should create component FAILED
[1]     Error: This test module uses the component AppComponent which is using a "templateUrl" or "styleUrls", but they were never compiled. Please call "TestBed.compileComponents" before your test.
[1]     Expected undefined to be defined.
```

Comment: i'm running into the same issue using webpack with aot.  everything works in production but not for tests.  are you saying that adding the moduleId property does fix the karma issue?