# why we use moduleId:module.id in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

Why is it necessary to  use `moduleId:module.id` at the time of using `templateUrl` in `Angular 2` Component .

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId:module.id,
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl:`app.component.html`,
})

export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular 2 website'; }
```

Comment: ` moduleId:module.id` for resolving relative path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 - What is the meanings of module.id in component?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178192/angular2-what-is-the-meanings-of-module-id-in-component)

Answer (score 5):

relative assets for components, like templateUrl and styleUrls in the @Component decorator.

moduleId is used to resolve relative paths for your stylesheets and templates as it says in the documentation.

**Without Module ID**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/my.component.html',
  styleUrls:  ['app/components/my.component.css'] 
})
```

**With Module ID**

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: 'my.component.html', 
  styleUrls:  ['my.component.css'] 
})
```