# Can the Angular CLI auto include moduleId in new components?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Quick question cause I may be blind or stupid. But is there a flag in the CLI so that I can have every component I generate add `moduleId: module.id` to my `@Component` decorator?

**Updates:**
Just to clear things up a little bit, I'm trying to use `ngu-sw-manifest` command from a package called `ng-pwa-tools`.

**More Updates:**
I'm aware that some people have said that the CLI recommends not to use `moduleId` anymore, but [I'm basing this need off of what a member of the Angular team has said](https://github.com/alxhub/io17/issues/16#issuecomment-309075516).

Comment: I'm pretty positive I read somewhere that `moduleId` wasn't recommended anymore, but I can't find the reference at the moment....

Comment: Might not be recommend, but when I was trying to use the Angular Mobile Toolkit I ran into some issue with (I think it was) the App Shell.

Comment: angular-cli uses webpack which doesn't need `moduleId`, you have to edit your question and add details about the problem with Angular Mobile Toolkit, not sure it's relevant to moduleid

Comment: What version of Angular CLI are you using?

Comment: I've been using v 1.1.1

Answer (score 1):

As is [explained elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37178813/754842), `moduleId` is not needed in `angular-cli` apps. The reason for this is that, under the hood, webpack automatically adds `moduleId` to the final bundle; hence, it is no surprise that there are no command line options having to do with `moduleId`.