# Angular 4 styleUrls file not found

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular 4.1.3 with Rails 5.1

I want use styleUrls to my component, but get error.

Here is error.

```
zone.js?4c9b:643 Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load app.component.css ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load app.component.css undefined
```

Here is my component.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import template from './app.component.html'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: template,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  name = '';
}
```

And this is my file structure

```
├── app
        app.component.css
|   ├── app.component.html
|   └── app.component.ts
|   └── app.module.ts
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: template,
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
```

Comment: what's wrong with `./app.component.css`? `./app.component.html` loads just fine.

Comment: `module.id` needs to be specfied  in order to load relative assets for your components. Here's a complete answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178192/angular2-what-is-the-meanings-of-module-id-in-component