# ng compiler won't see node_module (Error "Cannot find name 'module'")

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

Error:

> src/app/app.component.ts:4:12 - error TS2591: Cannot find name
>   'module'. Do you need to install type definitions for node? Try `npm i
>   @types/node` and then add `node` to the types field in your tsconfig.
>
> 4  moduleId: module.id,

When I try to run "ng build" in order to compile my angular files, I get error for every occurance of "module" var usage. I am sure the module is there, I can see it in node_modules folder and also I can ctrl+click on it and the file with module var would open.

I tried deleting whole node_modules dir and install again.

I left my tsconfig.json untouched since I am just learning so far, but here it is:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

here is example of usage in ts component:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent { }
```

Maybe it has something to do with my project structure, since I am not very sure what project structure to use. I am trying to build spring + angular aplication, with following structure:

[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw7G0.png)

Structure of angular app should be alright since it is generated by ng new command

Output path in angular.json is set to "outputPath": "../public", which should be in resource dir.

Do you have any idea what could be wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the module property in the component decorator. You no longer need to write `@Component({ moduleId: module.id })`, nor should you, `module.id` is automatically added by webpack. Maybe you are referring an old tutorial or code here, that is why module.id is still present here.

Refer this answer for more - [Angular - What is the meanings of module.id in component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178192/angular-what-is-the-meanings-of-module-id-in-component)

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not knew that, I removed module.id and it works just fine. I also found other workaround I posted here, but this seems like the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing following things from tsconfig.app.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
  "types": []
},
```

and adding this into tsconfig.json under compilerOptions

```
"types": ["node"]
```

Seems like compiler needs this "types": ["node"] option in order to find the module, and also it seems that by default this option is overriden in tsconfig.app.json..

I will not close this question a few days in case someone have a good explanation for me :-)

//EDIT: There is much better solution for this, I checked the answer as right.

Thank you