# TS2693 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: angular, angular6

I have the following child component

```
@EntryComponent({
  type: PhoneNumberComponent,
  name: 'PhoneNumberComponent'
})
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  providers: [],
  selector: '[phone-number-cmp]',
  templateUrl: '../views/phone-number.html'
})
export class PhoneNumberComponent {
  @Input() parentForm: FormGroup;
  @Input() control: AbstractControl;
  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() className: string;
  @Input() errorMessageRequired: string;
  @Input() errorMessagePattern: string;
}
```

somewhere in there is throwing the TSlint error `TS2693 'string' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`

I have tried to re assign the `@Input` variable/values to a local variable, without any success to get rid of that error.

```
  <div phone-number-cmp
       class="phone-number"
       [parentForm]="parentForm"
       [control]="officePhoneNumber"
       [label]="'Office Phone Number'"
       [className]="'officePhoneNumber'"
       [errorMessageRequired]="'Office phone number is required.'"
       [errorMessagePattern]="'Office phone number must contain 10 numbers. (e.g. XXX XXX XXXX)'"
  ></div>
  <div phone-number-cmp
       class="phone-number"
       [parentForm]="parentForm"
       [control]="faxPhoneNumber"
       [label]="'Fax Phone Number'"
       [className]="'faxPhoneNumber'"
       [errorMessageRequired]="'Fax phone number is required.'"
       [errorMessagePattern]="'Fax phone number must contain 10 numbers. (e.g. XXX XXX XXXX)'"
  ></div>
```

I'm passing the `string` values like the above.

Does anyone know how to get rid of that message?

Comment: The TS error usually gives a line number as well. You should probably look there

Comment: I have a few questions. Module.id why do you use that? I saw that in earlier versions of NGX but not later versions. Also @EntryComponent decorator, why is that used here? Is this a dynamically created component? If so, why not put this into the entrycomponents of the module and use a decorator? (I am asking because I have not seen this done before so, I am genuinly interested in knowing why and what the advantage might be versus putting it into a module)

Comment: Pretty sure your selector shouldn't be in [ ]s too

Comment: @PierreDuc, it gives me now line number, that would have been my first place to look also.

Comment: @IngeOlaisen please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37178192/angular-what-is-the-meanings-of-module-id-in-component, in general it helps with the relative paths.

Comment: @AdamDunkerley the reason i have my components set in `[]` is so i can then use them in html tags like so `<div my-component></div>` without that i can just call it the traditional component way `<my-component></my-component>` makes sense?

Comment: @Diego ah right, thanks, it's been a while, there's no mention of that anylonger. Probably because it's the default behavior these days. Paths in the templateUrl and styleUrls are relative to the component.
Anyway what about the entrycomponents decorator? It isn't mentioned in the documentation for Angular. Normal convention is like I mention to put that into the module in which it is declared.

Comment: Dont use bindings with static strings: `[label]="'Office Phone Number'"` should be `label="Office Phone Number"` and so on ...

Comment: @AndreElrico the `[label]`, `[className]` and so forth are meant to be "dynamic". Being that I'm trying to make this component as flexible as "possible", hence the binding of these attributes

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to pass in the values from the parent

```
.html
  <div phone-number-cmp
       class="phone-number"
       [parentForm]="parentForm"
       [control]="officePhoneNumber"
       [label]="officePhoneNumberLabel"
       [className]="officePhoneNumberClassName"
       [errorMessageRequired]="OfficePhoneNumberRequired."
       [errorMessagePattern]="OfficePhoneNumberPattern"
  ></div>
```

```
.ts
@EntryComponent({
  type: ContactInfoComponent,
  name: 'ContactInfoComponent'
})
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  providers: [],
  selector: '[contact-info-cmp]',
  templateUrl: '../views/contact-info.html'
})
export class ContactInfoComponent {
  @Input() parentForm: FormGroup;
  @Input() officePhoneNumber: AbstractControl;
  @Input() faxPhoneNumber: AbstractControl;
  @Input() emailAddress: AbstractControl;
  @Input() contactPerson: AbstractControl;
  OfficePhoneNumberLabel: string = 'Office Phone Number';
  OfficePhoneNumberClassName: string = 'officePhoneNumber';
  OfficePhoneNumberRequired: string = 'Office phone number is required.';
  OfficePhoneNumberPattern: string = 'Office phone number must contain 10 numbers. (e.g. XXX XXX XXXX)';
}
```

Comment: i think it is because you must assign an initial value to your @Input flaged variable but instead you can use \@Input var !: type ...

Answer (score 0):

i think it is because you must assign an initial value to your @Input flaged variable but instead you can use @Input var !: typee