# Make Lite-Server run as localhost:3000/parentdirectory and accessible as localhost/parentdirectory

Tags: angular, lite-server

I have an Angular2 app with this file structure:

- ParentDirectory

  - AppDirectory

    - app

      - app.component etc
    - node-module

      - @angular
      - lite-server
      - etc
    - index.html
    - styles.css
    - etc

I am testing the app with the lite-server and it runs beautifully on localhost:3000. To make it work with an Apache proxy I am setting up, I need it to run as locahost:3000/parentdirectory.

Using angular routes, I can easily make my pages look like they are coming from localhost:3000/parentdirectory, but that is only a superficial fix. If I go to localhost/parentdirectory, it still needs to work.

I looked at this question, which I think is very similar: [Can't change the base folder for lite-server in Angular 2 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35149408/cant-change-the-base-folder-for-lite-server-in-angular-2-application)

However, I'm new to all this and I'm afraid of breaking my currently working set-up.

My instinct is that I need to move my lite-server into the parentdirectory and change the root folder to look into my appdirectory, but I'm not sure if that will actually solve my problem.

I am hoping someone can give me concrete instructions or a link to documentation that outlines what I need to do to make this work before I start blindly changing things.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please try following assuming your application now lives in app folder and server started on it. I.e `https://localhost:3000/app`
1. index.html set `<base href='/app/' />`
2. In bootstrap `{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/app/'} // import it from router package`
3. In system.config.ts add `baseURL: /app/`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That seems to affect where my app is looking for its files, but not where the lite-server is running. The effect is an error that: GET http://localhost:3000/app/app 404 (Not Found). I also tried it using the '/appdirectory/' name instead of 'app' but had the same results.

Comment: Start lit server form parent directory