# Different root for Node lite-server than the folder holding package.json?

Tags: node.js, root, package.json, lite-server

Node newbie. I want to have Node's lite-server use a parent folder of my app as the http root, so that my app code can be saved within a subfolder from the html:

- /index.html -- want lite-server to serve this
- /js/angularApp/package.json -- location of my Node app and node_modules folder

Perhaps a command-line argument when running lite-server? I'm using a tutorial `package.json` containing a defined cli script "start":

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
```

Thanks for tips,

Ted

Comment: Tried \"lite-server -s ../../\" and npm start from package.json subfolder -- no dice

Comment: Tried \"lite-server -baseDir ./../../\" -- nope

Comment: Eureka! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35149408/cant-change-the-base-folder-for-lite-server-in-angular-2-application I added a bs-config.js file in my app root, causing BrowserSync to work with lite-server to make a specified path to be the doc root