# Lite-server does not detect a `bs-config.json` or `bs-config.js` override file

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, lite-server

I'm trying to run angular2 based first app. I followed [**angular2**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html) steps. When i run command `npm start` then its giving following error in the terminal

> Did not detect a bs-config.json or bs-config.js override file. Using lite-server defaults...

And also browser returning `404 error` for index.html file (`angular-project/app/index.html`)

I check lite-server version is `"lite-server@^2.2.0",` and npm version `3.7.3`, also i followed this accepted [**answer instructions**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35149408/cant-change-the-base-folder-for-lite-server-in-angular-2-application?answertab=active#tab-top) but still facing same issue. Can anyone guide me how can fix it, I will appreciate. Thank You.

Comment: In [Wrap up section](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#build-and-run) different project structure than described in question. Please ensure that you have followed tutorial correctly.

Comment: You have to added bs-config.js file in the directory from which you run npm start.

Comment: @AndriyIvaneyko Thank you so much for the guide line, i didn't added the `bs-config` in the root. Your solution is worked for me Thank You +10.

Comment: @Mr.Developer Great that suggestion suits for you. Adding it as answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Wrap up section](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#build-and-run) different project structure than described in question. Please ensure that you have followed tutorial correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I see you are running lite-server 2.2.0; anyone else looking for help with this error should make sure they are running lite-server 2.0 or greater as that's when config file support was introduced.

Also, it can throw this error if there is a problem executing the bs-config.js, so check your config file for anything that *could* be erroring (including but not limited to syntax errors).  For me I had forgotten to install the `http-proxy-middleware` so lite-server errored when it tried to execute the first line of my bs-config.js, which was `var proxy = require('http-proxy-midleware');`.  An `npm install --save-dev http-proxy-middleware` fixed this error for me.

HT: [this](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server/issues/41) github issue.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you have seen this warning message

> Did not detect a bs-config.json or bs-config.js override file. Using lite-server defaults...

is probably that you have a definition in your `package.json` which describes what should happen once you trigger the `npm start` command, like:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server -c bs-config.json\" ",
...
}
```

Therefore, in short you need to either provide the `bs-config.json` file with the desired browser-sync configuration or modify the the above command.

Moreover, angular2 has now its famous [quick-start](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) example on github.

Answer (score 0):

I made this account specifically to second the answer made by Patrick on July 12th.
If your bs-config cannot be found it may be because you do not have the proper packages. In my case I had `http-proxy-middleware`, but was missing `connect-history-api-fallback`.

Make sure to check/install all the node packages used in your bs-config!